# Why does this rewrite rule change fix my 404

Tags: mod-rewrite

At document root WordPress <s>has</s> had this .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

One non-WordPress directory was coming up as 404 with a WordPress "not found" page.  That directory has a basic auth .htaccess

```
AuthUserFile /home/foo/.htpasswd
AuthName "FOO Admin"
AuthType Basic

<Limit GET>
        require valid-user
</Limit>

RewriteEngine off
```

Changing `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`  to `RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]` fixed the problem.

Why did it fix it?  Does it tell mod_rewrite not to look at current dir (.) but at sub-dirs (./)?

I really want to understand this process more clearly.

PS I have left the `RewriteEngine off` in this post as I did try it in the auth htaccess- I found that whether it came before or after the auth did not matter.  It did not appear to have any effect.

Comment: `RewriteEngine` is a mod_rewrite directive that has no effect on `mod_auth` directives. About the other question, maybe the problem is `RewriteBase` is not root and it is necessary to define the prefix. In this case, I guess is /foo. If so, `RewriteBase /foo` and `RewriteRule . /foo/index.php [L]` should replace the actual directives. Just a guess, though.

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  Why would directories with no `mod_auth` directive load fine with the original `mod_rewrite` directives but directories which had a `mod_auth` directive would generate a 404?

Comment: You say: `directories`, plural. That's sometimes true for mod_auth directives, but WP rule set is placed only once in the install directory.

Comment: WP htaccess with RewriteRules (above) is at document root.  In directories below doc root IF there was an htaccess with auth directives it gave 404 with original rule.  Other directories without htaccess with auth did not give 404.